# Proof involving Boundedness of a Poisson equation

Tags: numerical-methods, partial-differential-equations

I am struggling with this assignment question for numerical analysis:

Suppose that $0<a<b<∞$, and $f(x)∈C^0$. Consider a Poisson equation
$$ u_{xx} = -f(x), x\in(a,b)$$
with the boundary conditions $u(a)=u(b)=0$.

If a solution $u(x)$ actually exists, show that $ ‖f‖_∞ \ge \frac{8}{(b-a)^2}‖u‖_∞.$

The professor gave us a vague tip on introducing a variable involving $\frac{(x-a)}{(b-a)}$. But how should I use it??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $u\equiv 0$, then the inequality holds trivially. If not, then $|u(x)|$ attains an absolute maximum at some critical point $c\in (a,b)$ of $u$ (i.e., $u_x(c)=0$). Since $|a-c|+|c-b|=|a-b|$, one of $|a-c|\leq\frac{1}{2}|a-b|$ and $|c-b|\leq\frac{1}{2}|a-b|$ holds. We first assume $|a-c|\leq\frac{1}{2}|a-b|$. By [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem), we have
$$
u(a)=u(c)+u_x(c)(a-c)+\frac{u_{xx}(\xi)}{2!}(a-c)^2
$$
for some $\xi\in (a,c)$. Since $u(a)=0$ and $u_x(c)=0$, we deduce that
\begin{align}
\| u \|_{\infty}=|u(c)|=&\left| -\frac{u_{xx}(\xi)}{2!}(a-c)^2\right| \\
=&\frac{|f(\xi)|}{2!}|a-c|^2 \\  
\leq&\frac{\|f\|_{\infty}}{2!}\cdot \frac{|a-b|^2}{4} \\
=&\frac{(b-a)^2}{8}\|f\|_{\infty}.
\end{align}
The case where $|c-b|\leq\frac{1}{2}|a-b|$ can be proved similarly.

Comment: I understand it now, thank you!